# Generate sources from a local jar file in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a locally stored jar file that I believe I need to generate the sources in order to consume it in my project.

I am using JDK 8, IntelliJ and Maven 3.5.2

I have installed the jar file into my local .m2 folder.

Perhaps I am missing a goal in my maven lifecycle or a plugin?

Not had to use a local jar dependency before so any help appreciated (I'm a tester not a developer)

I've attached a screenshot (apologies for all the obfuscation of package names that I feel might be commercially sensitive - possibly overkill!)

Note the red underlining in the src test....folders where the classes cannot access those within the jar dependency.

I *have* added the dependency within the pom.xml file also and it shows no errors.

[image]

I feel I should have run something like -Dsources=target/mycool-project-3.0.17-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar when using the mvn install:install-file command (which I used originally when installing to my .m2.  However I tried this with no success.

Or maybe I need to mark the resources as a root within IntelliJ

Currently in Project Structure -> Libraries I see:

[image]

Comment: when you do `mvn clean install` what do you get as a result ?

Comment: You don't need to generate sources to consume a JAR from Maven.  What is your real issue?   The source files from the JAR should not appear in your project /src tree.

Comment: Hi, thanks both.  Noted: have removed jar from tree.  a mvn clean install generates numerous errors e.g. "Compilation failure: symbol: class MyClass  location: package com.mydependency.package.utils".  So in IntelliJ, the classes I need from the depenency in my .m2 are not found / compiled

Comment: Can you run mvn clean install -U? Is it possible that the classes you are looking at are in the jar but your local snapshot is not refreshed from repo and does not have the latest changes?

Comment: @rslj I have tried mvn clean install -U with same error.  This .jar comes bundled as latest version from within repo. I don't understand why all the class files under External Libraries are shown as decompiled class files as opposed to, say, JUnit which I am bringing in in the same way - from my local .m2

Comment: I've just noticed that the sources are in red in the Project Structure -> Libraries: I have updated the original question